# Why does JNI not loading my shared object files

Tags: java, linux

I have a MOXA Box which I need to get going. I am running Linux 4.15.0 and downloaded the .so files from https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/controllers-and-ios/i-o-library/mxio-programming-library#resources .

I installed the librarys, they are installed to /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include.
Now my Java is using

```
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/jni
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

Iam using 'openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14'.
so I need to either add /usr/local/lib to this path via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or move the files to /lib, am I correct?
Now I have tried both but it is still giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jniwrapper.LibraryNotFoundException: MXIO cause: MXIO: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at com.jniwrapper.Library.loadLibrary(Native Method)
    at com.jniwrapper.Library.a(SourceFile:140)
    at com.jniwrapper.Library.load(SourceFile:130)
    at com.jniwrapper.Library.getFunction(SourceFile:257)
    at com.jniwrapper.Library.getFunction(SourceFile:275)
    at org.moxxa.Moxxa.init(Moxxa.java:66)
    at org.moxxa.Moxxa.main(Moxxa.java:21)
```

This is what I do in my code but we are not getting past mox.init()...
Where does the .so files have to be so that my java can find them. Do I have to provide the .a files and the .h files also? I wouldn't think so. Or is the 'new Library("MXIO");' wrong?

```
public class Moxxa
{
private Library lib = new Library("MXIO");
private final int MXIO_OK = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Moxxa mox = new Moxxa();
    System.out.println("Init: "+mox.init()); //-> We are not going past this...
    System.out.printf("Version: 0x%x\n",mox.getDllVersion());
    
    int handle = mox.connect("192.168.127.254", 502, 5000);
    System.out.printf("Connect: 0x%x\n", handle);

//        Thread.sleep(4000);
    
    byte[] fw = mox.readFirmwareRevision(handle);
    
    for (byte b : fw)
        System.out.printf("%x ", b);
    
    for (int i=0; i<3000; i++)
    {
        long l = mox.E1K_DI_Reads(handle, (byte)1, (byte)4);
        
        System.out.println(l);
        
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    System.out.println("Check Connection: " + mox.checkConnection(handle, 3000));
    
    mox.disconnect(handle);
    
}

public Moxxa()
{
    //do something later
}


/**
 * Initiate the socket
 * @return int - Succeed MXIO_OK. Fail Refer to Return Codes.
 */

public int init() throws MXIOException
{
    Function  func = lib.getFunction("MXEIO_Init"); //--> This call fails already!
    func.setCallingConvention(Function.CDECL_CALLING_CONVENTION);
    
    Int ret = new Int();       
    func.invoke(ret); 
    if ((int)ret.getValue() == MXIO_OK)
        return (int)ret.getValue();
    else
        throw new MXIOException("Fehler: "+(int)ret.getValue());
}

/**
 * This function establishes a connection to the port of the Ethernet
 * I/O. Once a connection is established, a handle will be returned for
 * additional functions.
 * @param sIp IpAdresse
 * @param port
 * @param timeout
 * @return connection handle
 * @throws MXIOException
 */

public int connect(String sIp, int port, int timeout) throws MXIOException
{
    Function  func = lib.getFunction("MXEIO_E1K_Connect");
    AnsiString ip = new AnsiString(sIp);
    Int16 wPort = new Int16(port);
    Int32 dwTimeOut = new Int32(timeout);
    
    Int con = new Int();
    Int ret = new Int();      
    
    Parameter[] parms = new Parameter[5];
    parms[0] = ip;
    parms[1] = wPort;
    parms[2] = dwTimeOut;
    parms[3] = new Pointer(con);
    parms[4] = new AnsiString("");
    
    func.invoke(ret, parms);        
    if ((int)ret.getValue() == MXIO_OK)
        return (int)con.getValue();
    else
        throw new MXIOException("Fehler: "+(int)ret.getValue());
}


/**
 * This will close the connection with the Ethernet I/O; the handle
 * will be invalid.
 * @param conHandle
 * @return int Succeed MXIO_OK. Fail Refer to Return Codes.
 *
 */
public int disconnect(int conHandle) throws MXIOException
{
    Function  func = lib.getFunction("MXEIO_Disconnect");
    Int con = new Int(conHandle);
    Int ret = new Int();       
    func.invoke(ret, con);        
    if ((int)ret.getValue() == MXIO_OK)
        return (int)ret.getValue();
    else
        throw new MXIOException("Fehler: "+(int)ret.getValue());
}

/**
 * the connection is established, a handle will be returned for additional functions.
 * @param conHandle Handle of the I/O connection.
 * @param timeout Timeout value in milliseconds for network connection.
 * @param status    Connection status.
                    0: Check connection ok.
                    1: Check connection fail.
                    2: Check connection timeout.
 * @return  Succeed MXIO_OK.
            Fail Refer to Return Codes.
 */
public int checkConnection(int conHandle, int timeout) throws MXIOException
{
    Function  func = lib.getFunction("MXEIO_CheckConnection");       

    Int8 state = new Int8();
    Int ret = new Int();
    
    Parameter[] par= new Parameter[3];
    par[0] = new Int(conHandle);
    par[1] = new Int32(timeout);
    par[2] = new Pointer(state);
    func.invoke(ret, par);        
    if ((int)ret.getValue() == MXIO_OK)
        return (int)state.getValue();
    else
        throw new MXIOException("Fehler: "+(int)ret.getValue());
}

/**
 * This will get the DLL version.
 * @return int The DLL version. Version 2.0.0.0 is expressed as value 0x2000.
 */
public int getDllVersion()
{
    Function  func = lib.getFunction("MXIO_GetDllVersion");
    func.setCallingConvention(Function.CDECL_CALLING_CONVENTION);
    
    Int ret = new Int();       
    func.invoke(ret);        
    return (int)ret.getValue();
}

/**
 * This function code is used to read the status of a group of
    contiguous D/I channels.
 * @param conHandle
 * @param slot
 * @param startChannel
 * @param count
 * @return contiguous D/I channel’s
            values; each bit holds the value of one channel.
            A bit value of 0 represents the digital input
            status of the start channel. A bit value of 1
            represents the second digital input channel’s
            status. The values of the unused bits are
            random.
 * @throws MXIOException
 */
public long E1K_DI_Reads(int conHandle, byte bytStartChannel, byte bytCount) throws MXIOException
{        
    Function  func = lib.getFunction("E1K_DI_Reads");
    
    Int32 dwValue = new Int32();        
    Int ret = new Int();
    
    Parameter[] par= new Parameter[4];
    par[0] = new Int(conHandle);
    par[1] = new Int8(bytStartChannel);
    par[2] = new Int8(bytCount);
    par[3] = new Pointer(dwValue);
    func.invoke(ret, par); 
                    
    if ((int)ret.getValue() == MXIO_OK)
        return dwValue.getValue();
    else
        throw new MXIOException("Fehlercode: "+ (int) ret.getValue());
    
}
}
```

Comment: *Now my Java is using...* That's just a textual listing. How are you actually setting `java.library.path` and what is its real value?